# cakephp - issue for joining multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

I am joining multiple tables like the following.

```
        $recommend_logs = $this->RecommendingProductLog->find('all', array(
                'recursive' => 2,
                'fields' => array('Product.ProductName', 'Product.Gender', 'Product.Price', 'RecommendingProductLog.preference', 'Brand.BrandName'),
                'conditions' => array('RecommendingProductLog.user_id' => $user_id),

                'contain' => array('Product', 'Product.Brand')
    ));
```

I am getting this query from log.

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Product`.`ProductName`, `Product`.`Gender`, `Product`.`Price`, `RecommendingProductLog`.`preference`, `Brand`.`BrandName`, `Product`.`id` FROM `database`.`recommending_Product_log` AS `RecommendingProductLog` LEFT JOIN `database`.`Products` AS `Product` ON (`RecommendingProductLog`.`Product_id` = `Product`.`id`) WHERE `RecommendingProductLog`.`user_id` = 32
```

Even though 'Product' table is a child table of 'Brand' table, somehow I don't see 'Brand' table in the query. That's why I am getting an error 'Unknown column 'Brand.BrandName' in 'field list'.

I specified 'Brand' in the Perfume model as 'belongsTo' and 'Perfume' in RecommendingPerfumeLog model and 'Perfume' as hasMany in Brand model.

can somebody point where the problem is?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly put the foreign keys on the respective tables of the relation? In this case Product have to have a a key with the name brand_id and it must be a foreign key to the brand id field.

Also check [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) and try to put your joins.

I don't remenber this 'contain' field from the docs. Are you using the latest version?